# How to continue a line in Latex in math mode?

Tags: amsmath, multline

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\Psi(\Gamma_{k},x)= x\,(x-1)^{(6k-2)}\,\left(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k)\right)\left(x^2-(k+3)x+2\right)\\\,\left(x^2-(2k+4)x+1\right)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to write this mathematical equation in Latex. But how to break such kind of equation such that it lies in the paragraph itself. In my case, it comes out of the margin in the page.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use a simple `align*`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Psi(\Gamma_{k},x) =x(x-1)^{(6k-2)} & \times\bigl(x^3-(3k+5) x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k) \bigr) \\ & \times \bigl(x^2-(k+3)x+2\bigr)\bigl(x^2-(2k+4)x+1 \bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multline*}
    \Psi(\Gamma_{k},x)= x\,(x-1)^{(6k-2)}\\
    \cdot\left(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k)\right)\\
    \cdot\left(x^2-(k+3)x+2\right)\cdot\left(x^2-(2k+4)x+1\right)
    \end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of `multline` so here is my take using `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools`

The look is similar to Sebastianos answer, but does not use alignment on `=`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % already loaded through amssymb
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft \Psi(\Gamma_{k},x)= x(x-1)^{(6k-2)}
  \\
  &\times\bigl(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k)\bigr)
  \\
  &\times\bigl(x^2-(k+3)x+2\bigr)\bigl(x^2-(2k+4)x+1\bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This is the type of alignment (when I'm not aligning on relations) that I use all the time in my edits. It comes from https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf, see section 3.3.4

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to break your formula into several lines in column, you can use the split environment. See this little example (first edit) with the very good suggestion of @Bernard user (see the first comment).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
\Psi(\Gamma_{k},x) & = x(x-1)^{(6k-2)}\\
& \phantom{=}\cdot \left(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k)\right)\left(x^2-(k+3)x+2\right)\\
& \phantom{=}\cdot \left(x^2-(2k+4)x+1\right)
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**: Here I have approved the suggestion of the very good user @dailef (see your comment).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
\Psi(\Gamma_{k},x) = {} & x(x-1)^{(6k-2)}\\
& \cdot \left(x^3-(3k+5)x^2+(2k^2+8k+7)x-(3+3k)\right)\left(x^2-(k+3)x+2\right)\\
& \cdot \left(x^2-(2k+4)x+1\right)
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe it would look better with a `\phantom{=}`?

Comment: Less typing if you use `= {} &` on the first line, and remove the `\phantom` on line 2 and 3.